# Get count() of data for the last 12 months, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am attempting to return a count of my users anniversaries by month on a rolling basis, which I will display in flot charts.

I think I nearly have it figured out, but I am struggling with getting the format of my column to match the comparison month.

```
//return an array of the last 12 months.
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) { 
  $months[] = date("Y-m", strtotime( date( 'Y-m-01' )." -$i months"));  
 }

//$months dumps as:  array(12) { [0]=> string(7) "2015-03" ...}

// find members where the anniversary column matches the $months[$i]
foreach ($months as $key => $value) {
  $renewals[] = User::where('anniversary',  '=', $value)->count();  
}
```

The format of the anniversary column is 2014-4-30.  How to I just grab the 'Y-m' of that column to compare to $month?

Comment: Is your anniversary column of the time stamp type? Or is it a date like 2015-04-23?

Comment: No, it is a imported value  - type Date, format:  2014-4-30

Comment: Ok see answer for an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
  $renewals[] = User::where('anniversary', 'LIKE', $value.'%')->count();
```

That would accept any day and only match month and year.  Of course there probably are better ways to accomplish this without using LIKE.

Alternatively you could get an array with months that has first and last day and use Laravels whereBetween method.

```
$renewals[] = User::whereBetween('anniversary', array($firstDay, $lastDay))->count();
```